# Vuejs not reading property from mixins and export NOT FOUND error.

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, babeljs

I have been on this error for 3 days, not sure if this is a bug, but I installed vuejs from [vuejs/vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli)

Using the following instructions:

```
npm install -g vue-cli 
vue init webpack foo.com
cd foo.com
npm install
npm run dev
```

So far it works, now I created a directory structure like this inside `src/`

```
— src
   — assets
   — filters
   — config
   — components
       Profiles.vue
       Login.vue
   profiles.js
   routes.js
   main.js
```

So, in `routes.js` I have something like this.

```
// routes.js
import ProfilesView from './components/Profiles.vue'
import LoginView from './components/Login.vue'

const routes = [{
  path: '/profiles',
  component: ProfilesView 
},
{
  path: '/login',
  component: LogoutView
}]

export default routes
```

So far, I have no issue with above code, the problem comes from these two below files either `profiles.js` or `Profiles.vue`

Here is **profiles.js**

```
const profiles = Vue.mixin({
  data: function () {
    return { profiles: [] }
  },
  methods: {
   fetchProfiles: function(){....},
   mounted: function(){ this.fetchProfiles() }
})

export default profiles
```

Here is **Profiles.vue**

```
<template lang="html">
  <div> {{ profiles }}<div>
</template>

<script>
  import { profiles } from '../../profiles'
  export default {
    mixins: [profiles],
    data () {
      return { profiles: [] }
    },
    mounted () {}
  }
</script>

<style lang="css">
</style>
```

With the above code, I get these errors.

```
profiles.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (profiles.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 1995fd0fa58cb1432d6f:659)
    at fn (bootstrap 1995fd0fa58cb1432d6f:85)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (app.js:55806)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 1995fd0fa58cb1432d6f:659)
    at fn (bootstrap 1995fd0fa58cb1432d6f:85)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Profiles.vue:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 1995fd0fa58cb1432d6f:659)
    at fn (bootstrap 1995fd0fa58cb1432d6f:85)
    at Object.__webpack_exports__.a (app.js:56033)
```

If I add `import Vue from 'vue'` to `profiles.js` the above error gets replaced with this one:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'components' of undefined
    at checkComponents (vue.esm.js:1282)
    at mergeOptions (vue.esm.js:1363)
    at mergeOptions (vue.esm.js:1379)
    at Function.Vue.extend (vue.esm.js:4401)
    at Object.exports.createRecord (index.js:47)
    at Profiles.vue:26
    at Object.<anonymous> (Profiles.vue:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 625917526b6fc2d04149:659)
    at fn (bootstrap 625917526b6fc2d04149:85)
    at Object.__webpack_exports__.a (app.js:56036)
```

This is complaining about the `mixins: [profiles],` in `profiles.js`, I am thinking `profiles` prop is undefined, but that is not the case. For some reason `Profiles.vue` is not reading or reading the correct data from `profiles.js` because I also get this error always:

```
[HMR] bundle has 1 warnings
client.js:161 ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Profiles.vue
6:11-15 "export 'profiles' was not found in '../../profiles'
```

It is complaining `export default profiles` isn't found in `profiles.js` even though it clearly does. I even tried using require, changing the paths ... everything. Nothing works.

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: can you provide a repository link? Seeing as you omitted parts of your code (which is generally good for readability purposes), it's hard to tell which specific parts of your code are being referred by the error messages.

Comment: `import { profiles } from '../../profiles'` is incorrect since you aren't exporting an object with property named `profiles`. Try `import profiles from '../../profiles'`

Comment: agreed with @thanksd !!! also if you just want to use the mixin locally then don't use (Vue.mixin)[https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin] as it creates a global mixin that may conflict with other components and lead to unintentional behaviour

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are importing `profiles.js` in the wrong way:

```
import { profiles } from '../../profiles'
```

Since you are using `export default`, it should be

```
import profiles from '../../profiles'
```